# docker: is "Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions" something to be mindful of?

Tags: python, docker, image, pip, containers

I am running a docker container (used by me and me only) on a shared ssh server. Recently, I needed to install a new package through pip, and noticed the following warning:

> WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead

Now: I don't care about the container itself since it gets destroyed once I'm done with it anyway (I use docker run (...) --rm), but I'm concerned about the host machine. As far as I know, containers are supposed to be 100% isolated, meaning that in case of any "conflicting behaviour with the system package manager", they will affect at most the container's and not the host's. Correct? Does that mean that I can safely ignore the message? Anything else I should be mindful of with respect to the host machine?

Sorry for the stupid question, but I am a docker noob. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I'm concerned about the host machine. As far as I know, containers are supposed to be 100% isolated, meaning that in case of any "conflicting behaviour with the system package manager", they will affect at most the container's and not the host's. Correct?*" Yes. "*Does that mean that I can safely ignore the message?*" Yes again. But still can I recommend you to read https://pythonspeed.com/articles/root-capabilities-docker-security/ and the entire set of articles at https://pythonspeed.com/docker/ ?